# Why is making a new line with FileInput?

Tags: python, csv

I'm removing a line in a *CSV* file to replace an element and then add a new one later.

But when I'm adding a new element (substitution) it's like python creates a new line when persists it.

**output file**

```
A;B;C;D
;new_element
A;B;C;D
;new_element
```

**expected output file**

```
A;B;C;D;new_element
A;B;C;D;new_element
```

**How I'm treating the file**

```
with FileInput(files=[CSV_FILE], inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        line_splitted = line.split(";")
        line_splitted[2] = line_splitted[3]
        line_splitted[3] = 'new_element'
        new_line = ';'.join(element for element in line_splitted)
        print(new_line)
```

Comment: Presumably `line` ends with a trailing `\n` that stays when you `str.join()`. To fix this, [`strip()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp) the `line` before you `split()`.

Comment: Thanks! But I just read the comment below though. So, when you joining in python the lines ( "\n") reminds once you split?

Comment: @Hikager The newlines aren't involved in the splitting at all. Here's an exercise: Split the string `"1;2;3;4;5+"` on semicolons: you get `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5+']`. Makes sense, right?. Now imagine you replaced the `'4'` with `'5+'` and the `'5+'` with `'new_element'`, and then joined by semicolons, you'd expect `1;2;3;5+;new_element`. Makes sense, right? Now imagine the `+` was a `\n`.

Comment: That make sense! So it's basically that the last element has the "\n" and when I decide to join into a deeper position it makes my line split (Because the last element  has a carriage return joined).  @Pranav Hosangadi thanks a lot for clarifying this to me. I just  didn't want only to get resolved this but also understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the csv you are reading has newlines at the  end of each line, and you don't remove them, so they are still there. You can use strip for this:

```
with FileInput(files=[CSV_FILE], inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        line_splitted = line.strip('\n').split(";")
        line_splitted[2] = line_splitted[3]
        line_splitted[3] = 'new_element'
        new_line = ';'.join(element for element in line_splitted)
        print(new_line)
```